# Regarding decltype() for captured entities, which compiler is ISO compliant?

Tags: c++, lambda, c++17, language-lawyer, decltype

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main(){

    int i = 1;
    int& j = i;

    auto f2 = [j = j]() {
        std::cout
            << std::is_same_v<decltype(j), int&>
            << std::is_same_v<decltype((j)), int&>
            << std::is_same_v<decltype((j)), const int&>;
    };
    
    auto f3 = [=]() {
        std::cout
            << std::is_same_v<decltype(j), int&>
            << std::is_same_v<decltype((j)), int&>
            << std::is_same_v<decltype((j)), const int&>;
    };

    f2();
    f3();
}
```

The following output is the result of the c++17 standard

| gcc | clang | msvc |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | 001 | 010 |
| 110 | 101 | 101 |

Or all the compilers are wrong？

Comment: Clang looks correct to me. `(j)` is const in both cases, and parentheses disable specialized handling of variables in `decltype` which otherwise makes `decltype(j)` return non-const in the second case.

Comment: @余国良 I can say that as for the second lambda then only gcc is correct.:)

Comment: See also See also [P2036R3 Change scope of lambda trailing-return-type](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2036r3.html#expr.prim.id.unqual) (made wording changes to some relevant sections and examples).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Clang is correct; the results given by Clang conform to the wording introduced by [P0588R1](https://wg21.link/P0588R1), which was accepted after the publication of C++17 but has DR status, meaning that it is recommended that implementations treat the original specification prior to P0588R1 as having been incorrectly drafted, and that the rules in P0588R1 should be applied by implementations even in C++17 mode and earlier.

The following example from P0588R1 illustrates the application of the rules to an example very similar to your second example, `f3`:

```
void f() {
  float x, &r = x;
  [=] {
    decltype(x) y1; // y1 has type float
    decltype((x)) y2 = y1; // y2 has type float const& because this lambda is not mutable and x is an lvalue
    decltype(r) r1 = y1; // r1 has type float&
    decltype((r)) r2 = y2; // r2 has type float const&
  };
}
```

In your example, you have the reference `j` instead of the reference `r`, but otherwise, it's the same. So `decltype(j)` should be `int&`, while `decltype((j))` should be `const int&`.

To elaborate, because `decltype(j)` and `decltype((j))` are not odr-uses of `j`, they denote the original entity from the enclosing scope. (There is no copy of `j` stored inside the lambda, because the lambda did not odr-use `j`; but even if the lambda had odr-used `j` and thus created a copy of it, non-odr-uses of `j` will not refer to that copy.) However, confusingly, the *type* of `j` inside the lambda is not necessarily the type of the entity that `j` denotes. Instead, to determine the type of `j`, we consider a hypothetical odr-use of `j`; then, we take the type from the type of a hypothetical member access expression to that hypothetical copy.

In the case of `decltype(j)`, because `j` is not parenthesized, `decltype` ignores the type of the *expression*, and gives the declared type of the denoted entity; this is `int&`, the declared type of the variable `j`. In `decltype((j))`, because `j` is parenthesized, `decltype` ignores the declared type of `j`, and looks at the type and value category of the *expression* `j`. Now, the hypothetical odr-use of `j` would result in an `int` member being declared in the closure type, but a hypothetical member access expression to that member would give an lvalue of type `const int`, because the lambda is not mutable. Consequently, `decltype((j))` is `const int&`.

Now, let's apply these rules to the case of `f2`. Here's where it gets a bit tricky because you have an *init-capture*. The *init-capture* actually introduces a new name `j` that shadows the `j` belonging to `main`. That new name denotes a member of the closure type, whose type is determined as if you had written

```
auto j = j;
```

except that the first `j`'s scope doesn't begin until after the closing square bracket of the *lambda-introducer*, so the second `j` refers to the `j` that belongs to `main`.

Now, any mention of `j` in the lambda body, whether an odr-use or not, denotes the `j` declared by the *init-capture*. That `j` has declared type `int`, so `decltype(j)` is `int`. For `decltype((j))`, we again consider a member access expression that would denote the member `j`; that member access expression would again be an lvalue of type `const int`, so `decltype((j))` is `const int&`.

Answer (score 1):

Clang is correct in both cases.

---

First of all, both snippets should print `?01`, i.e. `std::is_same_v<decltype((j)), const int &>` must be true in both.

The lambda is not `mutable`, meaning its `operator()` is `const`, hence any by-value captures appear to be `const` inside of its body (`j = 42;` inside of the lambda is a compilation error).

---

Now, regarding `decltype(j)`. `decltype` has [custom rules](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.3) for unparenthesized variable names, which makes it return the type specified in the variable declaration, even if we're inside of a `const` member function.

[When a capture-by-copy doesn't have an initializer](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10) (possibly because it's implicit), [`[expr.prim.lambda.capture]/11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10) kicks in:

> Every id-expression within the compound-statement of a lambda-expression that is an odr-use ([basic.def.odr]) of an entity captured by copy is transformed into an access to the corresponding unnamed data member of the closure type.
>
> [Note 7: An id-expression that is not an odr-use refers to the original entity, never to a member of the closure type.
> However, such an id-expression can still cause the implicit capture of the entity.
> — end note]

This means that `decltype(j)` (which is not an ODR-use) in the second snippet refers to the variable in the enclosing function, and returns the type used in its declaration, which is `int`.

As for the first snippet, [`expr.prim.lambda.capture]/6`](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda#capture-6) says (in a rather convoluted way) that captures with initializers are behave as if they created a named variable, so `decltype(j)` has to refer to that generated variable and not the one in the enclosing function.

The generated variable has type `int` (not `int &`, since we're capturing by copy), so this is what `decltype(j)` should return for the first snippet.

Comment: These two expressions   std::is_same_v<decltype((j)), int&>
            and  std::is_same_v<decltype((j)), const int&> contradict each other.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow Yes, did I say otherwise?