# What is the type of a by-value lambda capture of a reference?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Look at this program ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Yx6Er7hYK)):

```cpp
template <typename> struct TD;

void foo(int &par) {
    auto l = [par]() {
        TD<decltype(par)>();
    };
}
```

It intentionally doesn't compile, it uses a technique to make the compiler to display the type of `par`. Note that `par` is a by-value capture.

What is the type of `par` inside the lambda? Both gcc and clang give an error message which tells that `par`'s type is `int &`:

```
<source>:5:9: error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'TD<int &>'
```

On the other hand, MSVC complains about `TD<int>`:

```
<source>(5): error C2027: use of undefined type 'TD<int>'
```

If I change the standard to C++20 to MSVC, it also complains about `int &`.

[The current draft standard](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.capture#10.2) says:
For each entity captured by copy, an unnamed non-static data member is declared in the closure type. The declaration order of these members is unspecified. **The type of such a data member is the referenced type if the entity is a reference to an object**, an lvalue reference to the referenced function type if the entity is a reference to a function, or the type of the corresponding captured entity otherwise. A member of an anonymous union shall not be captured by copy.

Which compiler is correct? Have something related changed in the standard? If `par` really should be reference according to the standard, then why? As far as I understand the cited text, it supposed to be the referenced type, which is just `int`.

(Note: printing out `par`'s address in `foo` and in the lambda, they differ, so the compiler did make a copy. But then why is `par` in the lambda a reference? Did the compiler make an anonymous copy of`par` and then bind it to a non-const reference?)

Comment: [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/e6jK8xeq4) with `[par2 = par]` as capture.

Comment: [cpprefrence](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda) has similar example  (`f3()`)(capture with `=`)

Comment: @Jarod42: I think the `par2 = par` construct obeys some other rule. Regarding `f3()`, yes, it has a similar example, the variable `r` is a reference there. The page talks about some transformation: `(transformation not considered)`. I'm not sure what it is about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct type is `int&`, as explained in [[dcl.type.decltype] p1](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1).

> otherwise, if `E` is an unparenthesized *id-expression* or [...], `decltype(E)` is the type of the entity named by `E`.
> If there is no such entity, the program is ill-formed;

- [[dcl.type.decltype] p1.3](https://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.decltype#1.3)

`par` is an unparenthesized *id-expression*, and the type of the `par` entity is `int&`. It just remains to be shown that name lookup for the *unqualified-id* `par` finds the function parameter, not the captured variable in the lambda.

Name lookup *does* find the `int& par` parameter due to the rules in [[expr.prim.id.unqual] p3](https://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.id.unqual#3), which have the following example:

> ```cpp
> float f() {
>   float x, &r = x;
>
>   [=]() -> decltype((x)) {
>     // ...
>     decltype(r) r1 = y1; // r1 has type float&
>     // ...
>   }
> }
> ```

Even though `par` (or `r` in the standard example) is captured by copy, name lookup in an unevaluated operand does not find it.

A more detailed explanation of these rules can be found at [regarding the type derivation of lambda-captured variables, which is iso compliant](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76689371/5740428)

Also, If you wrote an *init-capture* `[par = par]`, the rules would apply again, and `decltype` would find the captured `par`.

---

Note: The C++20 wording for [expr.prim.id.unqual] may be easier to understand. This was changed in C++23 through [p2036 Change scope of lambda trailing-return-type](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2021/p2036r3.html#expr.prim.id.unqual)

#### Compiler Conformance

All compilers actually agree on this, but MSVC deviates in `/permissive` mode.
This is the default, so you're getting this surprising behavior.
`/std:c++20` disables MSVC compiler extensions, so it is as if you had written `/permissive-`. Adding the `/permissive-` flag on its own also makes MSVC think that the type is `int&`.

You can find an example of this feature in [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/permissive-standards-conformance?view=msvc-170):

> ```cpp
> decltype(auto) x = cond ? a : b; // char without, const char& with /Zc:ternary
> ```

Comment: Thanks. I checked older standards (C++11, C++14), and it seems that this behavior is very intentional. If a capture is not ODR-used, the "original" variable is used. And there is a rule, that if `declspec((x))` is used, then even though it doesn't ODR use `x`, it still uses the captured variant. I just don't understand the reason. It is **very** unexpected that the same name refers to different entities depending on these rules.